# Android Test Automation

Tags: android, unit-testing

How can i automate Android Apis for better quality ? How can i test the android applications to get a better quality of this software..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create tests in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586409/how-can-i-create-tests-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espresso is the best option coming forward to automate the android API's. Google has developed this testing kit for developers to write the unit test cases. Here's the Google's home page for espresso 
https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoStartGuide

Google has also implemented the sample test cases which help to learn espresso faster. Main advantage of espresso is its speed of execution and its work asynchronously meaning we are not explicitly required to write wait for actions in espresso. Developer should only perform action, waiting time taken care by espresso.
Here's link which gives start to espresso in easy to understand way:
http://www.stevenmarkford.com/android-ui-testing-with-espresso-basics-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you checkout [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) for testing Android apps.

Comment: your link dead now :(

Answer (score 1):

Use Robotium, its a good tool to use for Android Automation

Answer (score 1):

http://www.robotium.org/

Try robotium, i am using it, Its very easy for writing your Functional Test Cases and can be tested in all android Devices.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Seetest.
This is also an automation tool independent of any platform.  You can run the same test script across all the platforms like Android, IPhone, Windows Phone using this tool. Moreover it has a plugin for existing test frameworks like QTP, Testcomplete etc. Here is the link to download the trial version of the same.
http://experitest.com/support/download-2/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Webdriver/ selenium 2.0 android driver if you are looking for open source. its good and robust as well

Answer (score 0):

Try [bot-bot](http://imaginea.github.com/bot-bot/). Its a functional automation tool built over Robotium/Nativedriver. It have recording feature which helps in easy element identification and writing test-cases.

It uses "Ant" for build and running the tests. This helps in integration with continuous integration tools.

At the end of your test execution it generates emailable html reports with pass-fail status.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare Raspberry-Pi, you can also use that to speedup your test :) , much better than running on Emulator:

[Raspberry-PI for Android Test Automation](http://innovation.avg.com/2016/06/15/raspberry-pi-for-android-test-automation/)