# Android Studio - Unable to create Test module

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio

Just installed Android Studio to give it a try. I'm trying to create a test module for my application and, whatever the method I use, I always get the following error: **"Error: No AndroidManifest.xml file found in the main project directory..."**.

Methods I use:

1) from Android Studio: New > Module > Test Module
2) from command line: android create test-project -m "main_path" -n "project_name" -p "test_path"

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: As of [0.1.8 this is now supported in the IDE](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio018released).

According to the [documentation for the new build system](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) a separate project is no longer needed, which implies that a separate module may not be either. That said, getting test working within the IDE is still problematic. I've posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586409/how-can-i-create-tests-in-android-studio) that at least works for running tests from the command line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Chris. I'd rather run it from the IDE, but at least it works. Great tip.