# Is it possible to run/debug tests in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have created a project in Android Studio, added some instrumentation tests and I'm able to run them on a connected device via `./gradlew connectedCheck`. Is it possible to run these tests from Android Studio?

And more importantly, is it possible to debug these tests in Android Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test support is available as of 0.1.8, see [other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586409/how-can-i-create-tests-in-android-studio?rq=1#16881419).

Debugging support is available [since 0.1.9](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio019released).

Answer (score 1):

Testing support is not there, it'll be there in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for update. Do you know if there is going to be any support for unit tests that don't require an Android environment? Or is it always going to be the developer responsability to create a task, attach it to check, and compile and run those tests in there? It would be nice to have something like that as part of the android plugin (the same way the java plugin has it). Anyway, thanks a lot for replying.