# Create testing Android apk using gradle build system

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, robotium, build.gradle

I'm migrating my android project to gradle build system and I can't import my Android project from my Integration Test Android project.

I'm using multi-project configuration with several android-libraries and it's working great, but I'm having a problem setting up my testing project with multi-project settings. For external reasons I need to continue using this structure.

```
MyProject/
 | settings.gradle
 + MyApp/
    | build.gradle
    | src
    | res
    | libs
 + Instrumentation-Tests/
    | build.gradle
    | src
    | res
    | libs
```

my current configuration files look like:

settings.gradle:

```
include ':MyApp', 'Instrumentation-Tests'
```

MyAppp/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('.....jar')
    compile project('....')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

    }
}
```

And finally my `Instrumentation-Tests/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':MyApp')
    compile files('.....jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `gradle compileDebug` the project `MyApp` is compiled correctly (and all its modules) but the `Instrumentation-Tests` compilation fails because it can not find the android classes defined in `MyApp`.

I've read documentation and a lot of posts but I couldn't make it work, I do also tried using:

```
compile(project(':MyApp')) { transitive = true }
```

when declaring the dependency.

**Has anybody had the same problem?**
I'd like to include the output of the `MyApp` project dependency into the classpath of `Instrumentation-Tests` compilation, but I don't know if that is possible using the android `gradle` plugin.

Comment: Have you read up on stuff like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586409/how-can-i-create-tests-in-android-studio and this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing? I wonder if you followed those instructions but changed the location of the sourcesets if it would work with your current setup. You probably need to specify the test source directories relative to the project root.

Comment: I ended up moving all to the gradle structure, I do also moved all my instrumentation tests (unit and functional) inside the instrumentationTest folder and everything works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work (as of now) because you can only specify library projects as dependencies.

So for the case of `compile project(':MyApp')` *MyApp* should have been an Android library project with `apply plugin: 'android-library'` in it's *build.gradle*. Which certainly doesn't make sense.

To have a separate test project, you need something else (which I'm researching myself).

EDIT: Given up on testing with Gradle, use Ant for that.

Comment: I ended up moving all to the gradle structure, I do also moved all my instrumentation tests (unit and functional) inside the instrumentationTest folder and everything works!