# Unable to get Robotium to work in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, robotium, android-testing, ui-testing

I'm struggling to get Robotium to work on the gradle-based Android Studio and I can't find the way to do it

This is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            mavenLocal()
        }

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
   /* maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }*/
}

sourceSets {
    testLocal {
        java.srcDir file('src/test/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/test/resources')
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    sourceSets {
        instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'

    // Dependencies for the `testLocal` task, make sure to list all your global dependencies here as well
    testLocalCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testLocalCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
    testLocalCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    testLocalCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.+'
    testLocalCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:4.2'

    // Android Studio doesn't recognize the `testLocal` task, so we define the same dependencies as above for instrumentTest
    // which is Android Studio's test task
    instrumentTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    instrumentTestCompile 'com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4'
    instrumentTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    instrumentTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.1.+'
    instrumentTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:4.2'


}

task localTest(type: Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.testLocal.output.classesDir

    android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each { dir ->
        def buildDir = dir.getAbsolutePath().split('/')
        buildDir =  (buildDir[0..(buildDir.length - 4)] + ['build', 'classes', 'debug']).join('/')

        sourceSets.testLocal.compileClasspath += files(buildDir)
        sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath += files(buildDir)
    }

    classpath = sourceSets.testLocal.runtimeClasspath
}




check.dependsOn localTest
```

As you can see, I'm using Robolectric and Robotium
The problem I've got is whenever I try to create a Robotium test, like this one:

```
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import com.dlv.testing.MainActivity;
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

public class MainActivityUITest extends
        ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    private Solo solo;

    public MainActivityUITest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    public void testStuff() throws Exception {
        solo.assertCurrentActivity("Check on first Activity", MainActivity.class);
        solo.sendKey(Solo.MENU);

    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }
}
```

it cannot find any import, the project does not fail to compile in Android Studio, it just fails when I run the tests and if I remove the class and the references in the dependences, Robolectric works just fine

Comment: I think it is possible now to run robolectric tests from android studio. check out the following link from [big nerd ranch](http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/all-in-together-android-studio-gradle-and-robolectric/)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't successfully run any tests from Android Studio yet (see [How can I create tests in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586409/how-can-i-create-tests-in-android-studio)). You need to do it from the command line (note that you may need to clean first `./gradlew clean`):

To run the instrumentTests, use `./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest`

To run your test task, use `./gradlew localTest`

For future reference when Android Studio works better with test integration, you can set it up to run any given Gradle task. Go to 'Edit Configurations' and click the '+' button to add a new one. Choose 'Gradle' and then configure it to point to the correct gradle.build file and the task you want to run. I'm not sure what you would add in the 'Before launch' section, however, if anything.

All that being said, here's how I got my robotium tests to run:

1. I used the built-in Instrument Test configuration because I couldn't get the localTest task to work (I got the same errors as you did where it couldn't find any imports). I used the default folder structure with the `instrumentTest` folder, but it looks like you can just use the line `instrumentTest.setRoot('src/test')` to make it work the same with your setup.
2. I configured my build.gradle file like this:

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           mavenCentral()
       }
       dependencies {
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
       }
   }
   apply plugin: 'android'

   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
       // Included library modules
       ...

       // My regular dependencies
       compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
       ...

       // Test dependencies. Notice that all I have to include is robotium
       // because the rest just works using the instrumentTest configuration
       instrumentTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:4.3'
   }

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 17
       buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

       defaultConfig {
           minSdkVersion 7
           targetSdkVersion 16
       }

   }
   ```
3. I added the robotium library in Project Structure (`command-;` on my mac) as a maven libary.
4. I then wrote a test like this:

   ```
   import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
   import com.example.activity.WelcomeScreen;
   import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

   public class WelcomeScreenTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<WelcomeScreen> {
       private Solo solo;

       public WelcomeScreenTest() {
           super(WelcomeScreen.class);
       }

       protected void setUp() throws Exception {
           super.setUp();

           solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
       }

       public void testActivity() {
           // robotium assert
           solo.assertCurrentActivity("Welcome Screen", WelcomeScreen.class);
           // junit assert
           assertEquals(true, true);
       }
   }
   ```
5. I then ran the test via the command line `./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest` and it worked for me.

Comment: All I get when I run this is: error: package com.jayway.android.robotium.solo does not exist
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

Comment: I'm still missing one more part of the puzzle. When I do all this it says "package com.jayway.android.robotium.solo does not exist". Only if I add "compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:4.3'" does it work. But this looks like it is including my test class as part of the project source code does it not ?

Comment: Remember to restart/reimport the project after adding `instrumentTestCompile` pragma - this gave me a bit of the headache when writing the first test (robotium imports were unavailable) - tested and proven to work on Android Studio 0.4.2.