# can't run robotium unit test application on android

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, robotium

I've been trying to build a unit test project with robotium, but running it keeps failing with an error.

ComponentInfo{com.ha.team.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner} Empty test suite.

I've found a lot of links with this issue, but none seam to help.
[Why is the Android test runner reporting "Empty test suite"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381694/why-is-the-android-test-runner-reporting-empty-test-suite)
[Unable to get Robotium to work in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767974/unable-to-get-robotium-to-work-in-android-studio)

I've stated in my gradle file :

```
    sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/androidTest/java'] } }

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.4.1'
}
```

My test class :

```
public class ExampleTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainCardActivity> {

    private Solo solo;

    public ExampleTest() {
        super(MainCardActivity.class);

    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        try {
            solo.finalize();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getActivity().finish();
        super.tearDown();
    }

    @SmallTest
    public void test_login() {
        assertEquals(true, true);
    }
}
```

i have a package for the application : com.ha.team
and i've placed a test project under : src->androidTest->java->com.ha.team.test package.

Under run / debug configurations i'm running the project as android Test on the project's module with my test class : com.ha.team.test.ExampleTest

As i said, i've covered a lot of whats out there, but didn't find anything to help me with this issue.
Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

I miss the following in your gradle configuration file:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<your app ID>"
        minSdkVersion <your min sdk version>
        targetSdkVersion <your target sdk version>

        testApplicationId "<your test app ID>"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
```

The latest two lines are important.