# Instrumentation testing in Android Studio

Tags: testing, android-studio, android-testing

[image]I'm new to testing and currently trying to write some tests in Android Studio. I have a sample application module and now trying to figure out, whether the instrumentation test needs to be a module of its own or whether the tests should go inside the src folder... I have read contradicting information on the web. If anyone had a sample, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

With eclipse ADT plugin and older version of the SDK it was a requirement to put the integration tests in a separate module.

With the gradle build system and android-studio you should be able to put your integration tests in src/test/java and running them from the IDE or gradle command line without pain.

That's why you find contradicting information on the web.

Here is the [reference](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And what is the difference between putting it in the src folder and creating an Android Test Module through Android Studio inside my module? Currently I am not using gradle ...

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to create an 'Android Test Module' with Android-Studio (not sure I understand what you mean). Putting your test code in the same module as the sources under test seems a very good practice, no more, no less.

Comment: I edited my question and included a screenshot ... hope that helps to clarify.

Comment: It seems to be a screenshot from IntelliJ, not Android-Studio ... or it is how it looks on MacOSX ? (In my version of Android-Studio 0.2.9 I don't have those options, but I've those in IntelliJ !)

Comment: It's Android Studio 0.2.9. on Mac OS, inside "Project Structure"

Comment: OK... surprising. I think "Android Test Module" is a concept that won't survive to the new gradle build tool. So I don't recommend to use it on new projects.

Answer (score 2):

This post contains a very good explanantion on how to do the integration testing in Android Studio:
[How can I create tests in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586409/how-can-i-create-tests-in-android-studio)