# Programming non UI Android code

Tags: android, code-organization

So I'm currently in the process of developing a reasonably large app for Android. I'm the only dev on it. I'm trying to be as organized as possible.

My app sends (or will send) requests to an API and it responds in XML. So I had to write parsers for the different request answers, and while doing the first parser (I used the sdks XmlPullParser) I thought it would be good if I didn't have to test that on the phone (build + it launches the app on the phone).
I'm currently using Android studio.

So my question is:

How do I develop bits of my application that don't need the phone (like UI and user input...), but that still need the Android library (XmlPullParser for me) ?

thanks

Comment: I might have misunderstood you, but you could still use the emulator for this. Technically, the GUI is not a requirement for an application to be an application, if you understand.

Comment: The emulator would be even slower. Basically I want a way to launch and try the parsers I write, as if I was developping without the phone. The only thing I need to write and test my parsers is the Android library, there's no need to launch them with the emulator or the phone.

Comment: You can download an [implementation](http://www.xmlpull.org/impls.shtml#xmlpull) of the XML Pull Parsing API as a library, such as [kXML](http://kxml.org/index.html) (which is one of the implementations used in Android).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create tests in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586409/how-can-i-create-tests-in-android-studio)