# Best practices for Android Unit Testing?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity, junit, android-testing

I am developing a mobile android app. What are the most common libraries/frameworks used for Android unit testing? I feel that most of the business logic, database testing, Web services testing can all be done using JUnit.

However, what's the best approach for testing UI, the UI workflow, etc? For example, how can we test if the Android app launches a web browser successfully? Or how can we confirm if buttons, certain things are pressed successfully? Or if images are loaded successfully?

Comment: now there's already a lot of material out there. check the official website https://developer.android.com/training/testing/index.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use [JUnit](http://junit.org/) for unit testing and [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/) for instrumentation tests.

[This article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Robolectric/article.html) shows you a Hello World example with Robolectric

In recent times, I have been researching about integration testing in Android using [Arquillian Droidium](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-droidium).

If you want to test some code that consumes a REST API, you can mock it with [WireMock](http://wiremock.org/). With this library, you can mock REST APIs by code or even deploy a mock HTTP server in your own machine and set up your own mocked mappings.

For REST API mocks, I also recommend you to use [Mockable.io](https://www.mockable.io/).

Answer (score 8):

**2017 answer**

The Android documentation has a topical series called [Best Practices for Testing](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/index.html). I would start there.

Local Unit Tests and Instrumented Tests are set up by default when you start a new project. The general advice given is to use the local unit tests whenever possible. Sometimes this requires mocking an object that uses the Android API. The [documentation recommends](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#mocking-dependencies) using [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito) in these cases. When UI tests (instrumented tests) need to be done, Android provides the [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#Espresso) framework. There are also other tools available, like the [Exerciser Monkey](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html) (for stress testing) and [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) (for testing multiple app interaction).

**Example**

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43626962/3681880) for how to get started with tests in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [guide for automated user interface testing](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/index.html) on the Android Developers Website. I haven't tried it but it looks like what you've been looking for.