# Create unit tests in android studio

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, android-testing

I'm following [this](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html) tutorial.
What I want to do is to create unit tests with `AndroidJunitRunner`.

My directory in `app/src` looks like this:

```
androidTest
debug
main
release
```

android docs suggests that I create a `test/java` for my unit tests.
The problem is that in android studio I can't create a new directory if I'm on android project mode. And I should find the directory manually and create it manually.
Is there a way to automatically create these directories and tests for one flavor?
I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586409/how-can-i-create-tests-in-android-studio) question, which doesn't relate to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easiest to just create the folder manually in the directory.  Android Studio will notice it pretty quickly and it will show up in your `Android` view.

You will need to create the packages in the `test/java` folder too.  So if your package name is `com.foo.bar` you need to create the following dir structure in your `app/src` folder:

`test/java/com/foo/bar`

As an aside in the latest versions of Android Studio you don't need to use `AndroidJunitRunner` anymore.  Studio supports JUnit4 tests out of the box.

To make tests for a particular flavor you need to append the flavor name to the end of the test folder.  So if your flavor is `dev` then the folder structure would be:

`testDev/java/com/foo/bar`

Comment: tnx, one quick question: if I'm going to test a class in package: ``com.x.y.model`` should I create the same package in test directory?  
Also, I read in google docs that if I change a class method or something in source both unit tests and instrument tests are going to sync. but I don't see any sync here why?

Comment: Yes the test package should match the class under test.  Once you've made the test base directory though it's easy to make a test for a class by pressing cmd+shift+t and it will create the test in the correct place.  I'm unsure what you mean by `sync` sorry

Comment: tnx, just one more question: Are these tests are shipped to production code too?

Comment: No the tests are not compiled into the apk.  Also you'll note that in your build.gradle you can specify your test dependencies with `testCompile` so that they too are only used in the tests.

Comment: your answer and comments cleared so many things. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Just change to Project Mode and create the test folder. Take a look to the screenshot.

[image]

By the way, I think when you create a project the folder is already created.